# Woocommerce Paypal Pay with debit or credit card is intermittently not displaying

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I'm having problems with Woocommerce / Paypal not displaying the 'pay with debit or credit card option. Everything else is set up fine and payments are going through etc. 
https://burygreenpoultry.co.uk/online-courses/

If you look at the screenshot attached - this is what should appear but only does this say once every 20 times! I've found that countless people have experienced this but none of the solutions posted have fixed it for me. I've cleared cookies, tried different devices / browsers as well as checked the 'Allow customers to conveniently checkout directly with PayPal' in the payment settings in Woocommerce.

I can also confirm that the PayPal account is a business one, and that the 'allow guest checkout' option is enabled in the PayPal account. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even if your PayPal account is a business, and that the 'allow guest checkout' option is enabled in the PayPal account, PayPal have some restrictions for some countries to disallow guest checkout. Depending on the customer country, PayPal will change the interface.

[PayPal operating countries](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/country-worldwide)

Comment: Thanks for reply! Purchases have only come from UK and Spain, so I assume it's not this?

Comment: Also it's intermittent which doesn't make sense to me...sometimes it just works!

Comment: Then PayPal support guys maybe able to help

Answer (score 0):

For every checkout attempt, the PayPal system makes its own determinations about whether or not a guest checkout will be permitted. This determination can be based on many factors, but basically things like refreshing the checkout page many times is one of the things that causes attempts to look unusual and will intermittently disable guest, so don’t test that way.

TL;DR expected behavior from PayPal

Comment: Ah I never knew this, how should i test this specifically?

Comment: If you have seen guest checkout appear at least once, then everything you need/can do is already correct. The rest is a PayPal system decision